# WSO2 - ERROR - SourceHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown

Tags: wso2

Hi I have published rest api endpoint url in wso2 2.1.0 version and when I try to test it in API console, I get certificate_unknown error. How to add certificate for this endpoint url. The same published API is working from postman. I am able to see the response content in postman.

> HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length =
>   1277 HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
>   HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal,
>   certificate_unknown HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1, fatal: engine
>   already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal
>   alert: certificate_unknown HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1, fatal:
>   engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException:
>   Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown [2019-11-04 11:59:17,558]
>   ERROR - SourceHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert:
>   certificate_unknown javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert:
>   certificate_unknown
>           at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1647)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1615)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1781)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1070)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:896)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:766)
>           at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
>           at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doUnwrap(SSLIOSession.java:245)
>           at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:280)
>           at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:410)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:119)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:159)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:338)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:316)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:277)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

This url will give 500 error due to logical error in postman. The response content should appear in API console as well. But I get empty content for the response.

```
Request Headers
{
  "Accept": "application/json"
}
Response Body
no content
Response Code
500
Response Headers
{
  "cache-control": "must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store",
  "content-type": null
}
```

Comment: can u attach a screenshot plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to invoke the API resource with Try it out feature in Store UI?

Comment: Yes. I am trying from store UI

Comment: This certificate_unknown issue might occur when the browser is not trusting the server which has a self signed certificate. Hope you are having a self signed certificate (or default wso2 self signed certificate). When an API is invoking from the Store UI (Try it), the browser sends the request to Gateway which has a self-signed certificate (not CA-signed) and browser will not trust the server. So the request fails.

Comment: For the development environment, if a self-signed certificate is being used, it can be imported to browser. If it is the case, you can access the Gateway URL (https://<ip-address>:<port>) on a new tab of the same browser and trust the certificate from the browser.                                                                                                               Or else you can use CA-signed certificate for Gateway and import it to relevant key stores. Please refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Creating+New+Keystores.

Comment: I tried creating self signed certificate as well. still i get the same error

Comment: you don't need to create a new certificate, all you got to do is to open the api consumption link in another tab. Accept the certificate you should be all fine.

Answer (score 3):

Open the WSO2 API url in new tab (for which you are trying to do the testing from swagger console)  and accept the certificate, and then try again in WSO2 store.

Answer (score 1):

open the wso2 api in new tab browser such as https://wso2_ip:8243/ and https://wso2_ip:9443/
you can solve this problem with nginx and set certificate in nginx.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).